Jupyter notebook setup issue (jupyterlab plotly and convert to html)
I am currently facing the following problem, when I am trying to convert a notebook using nbconvert
Hi am getting the following error
jupyterlab error
After a bit of searching on the internet I realised that my jupyterlab-plotly does not seem to be setup correctly
jupyter lab list
I have install everything with conda (24.9.2)

plotly=5.24.1
jupyter=1.0.0
jupyterlab=4.2.5

I can provide more details about the different package I have installed.
Has anyone already faced an issue similar or is even able to reproduce that error ?
I have tried to reinstall miniconda from scratch several times, look on the internet about what seems to be a misinstall pacjage of jupyterlab-plotly
